# web.config urlmapping

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I have a comment form on my website on `contact.aspx`. I want to be able to put up a redirect from `/comment` (no extension) to point to `contact.aspx`.

I set up the following url mapping in my `web.config` and when I test locally it works fine. When I post it to production, the redirect doesn't happen and I get the IIS 404 error.

```
<system.web>
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
        <add
        url="~/comment"
        mappedUrl="~/contact.aspx"/>
    </urlMappings>
```

I'm assuming this is because IIS isn't serving up the request to the asp.net engine and I'm using a shared hosting environment (discountasp.net) so I don't have direct control over IIS to configure it there. I can always put in the subfolder and a default.aspx that will redirect for me, but I thought I would inquire about this route first.

What does the collective think?

Comment: DiscountASP.Net does offer MVC hosting.

Comment: their site says "Our Windows hosting platform is ASP.NET MVC 2.0 compatible." (http://www.discountasp.net/sp_mvc-hosting.aspx). That being said, for now I added a folder and default.aspx with a redirect. I may come back to this. Not sure when this site update will go out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your web host if they can configure your virtual directory to serve all requests through ASP.Net.

Many hosts (mine included) are willing to do this.  (Mention ASP.Net MVC, which requires this)

Comment: They say, `For IIS 6.0 users: Contact technical support to configure wildcard mapping to point to asp.net for the directory where you uploaded your MVC application.`